# HTML/CSS Make Icons transition to text in Website menu

Tags: html, css, icons

So I, like all of you have a menubar (header) on top of my website
and recently found out how to use icons.

Now What I need is a menu wich at first shows ONLY the Icons and when you hover over the text (e.g. HOME, SHOP, etc.) shows up to the right of the icon.

Any way to to this with css?

Thx!

Comment: You need to post up some code showing what you have tried and where exactly you are going wrong so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with CSS.

Here's an example:

Create a `<span>` class: `<span class="hideBeforeShow"></span>`.

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="hideBeforeShow">Test</span></li>
</ul>
```

Next, make sure you make the class hidden using `visibility: hidden;`:

```
li .hideBeforeShow
{
    visibility: hidden;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 7px;
}
```

(padding is added to separate it from the icon)

Next, you'll want to make it show when you hover over the `<li></li>` element. After you hover over it, you can select it by adding the class name afterwards:

```
li:hover .hideBeforeShow
{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Next, you'll want to hide the icon. Set the content to nothing, or hide the image, whatever you want to do.

```
li:hover:after
{
    font-family: none;
    content '';
}
```

You can substitute these 'font-awesome' icons with images instead. The same concept applies.

Here's the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xg9sgta7/2/) example. Play with it.